# RDD collect OOM issues

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, amazon-emr

I am trying to parse the input rdd into map with broadcast but running into memory issues on EMR. Below is the code

```
val data = sparkContext.textFile("inputPath")
val result = sparkContext.broadcast(data
          .map(x => {
            val row = x.split(",")
            if(row.length == 4) {
              if(row(3) == null) {
                (row(0).toString, "0")
              } else {
                (row(0).toString, row(3).toString)
              }
            } else {
              (row(0).toString, "0")
            }}).collect.toMap)

rdd.map(other operations).filter(x > result.value.contains(x)
```

It fails at line filter operation with

```
22/08/30 03:52:59 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Any insights will be helpful. The input data is less than 10GB and I have set `spark.driver.maxResultSize=40g` and `spark.driver.memory=45g`

Comment: Are you using a cluster? How much memory do your executors have? Because broadcasting a variable means sending a copy of the variable to each node. If some nodes don't have enough memory, the job will fail.

Comment: You could try while reading you can read data in batch using spark conf - `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` also you can repartition at level you are performing join. Repartition would help parallelize processing across executors.

Comment: cluster has a memory size of 60GB per instance